# C# Update Text of dynamically generated UserControl label

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, dynamic-usercontrols

I'm really struggling with C#. I've been given a project to work on, but most of my experience is in C. The purpose of the application is to ping an API and display the data from it in a windows form.

I can get the data, and dynamically display it, but I cannot figure out how to update the form with new data grabbed every 3 seconds.

The data source provides User info. There can be x amount of users. Because of this, and after tons of googling and reading other SO threads, I've determined the best route seems to be to create a UserControl and call it x times, adding each user to the screen. This works. However, I can't seem to update the controls with new data.

Here is my code:

UserControl:
UserStatus.cs

```
    namespace RCQMonitor
    {
        public partial class UserStatus : UserControl
        {
            public UserStatus()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public UserStatus(ExtensionInfo user) : this()
            {
                labelName.Text = user.Name;
                labelStatus.Text = user.DndStatus;
                labelStatic.Text = "Status:";
            }
        }
    }
```

UserStatus.Designer.cs

```
{
    partial class UserStatus
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.labelName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelStatic = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // labelName
            // 
            this.labelName.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.labelName.Name = "labelName";
            this.labelName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 15);
            this.labelName.TabIndex = 0;
            this.labelName.Text = "First Last";
            // 
            // labelStatic
            // 
            this.labelStatic.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelStatic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(118, 0);
            this.labelStatic.Name = "labelStatic";
            this.labelStatic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 15);
            this.labelStatic.TabIndex = 1;
            this.labelStatic.Text = "Status:";
            // 
            // labelStatus
            // 
            this.labelStatus.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(166, 0);
            this.labelStatus.Name = "labelStatus";
            this.labelStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 15);
            this.labelStatus.TabIndex = 2;
            this.labelStatus.Text = "label3";
            // 
            // UserStatus
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelStatus);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelStatic);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelName);
            this.Name = "UserStatus";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(311, 22);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelStatic;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelStatus;
    }
}
```

Form:
Form1.cs

```
namespace RCQMonitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            timer.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Program.GetPresence(); //This just grabs the new data, it works.
            this.Refresh();
        }

    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace RCQMonitor
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();

            
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Program.NumOfExtensions; i++)
            {
                var control = new UserStatus(Program.extensions[i]);
                control.Location = new Point(x, y);
                this.Controls.Add(control);
                y += control.Height;
            }

            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(350, 165);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "QMonitor";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label extLabel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label statusLabel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label statusLabel2;
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm very new to C#, so I've had to cannibalize examples to get this to work so far. I'm sure it's messy.

Since I'm adding the UserControls dynamically, how would I reference them in order to update them?